# Very slow product list issue with magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a category called **new arrivals** which has 5 subcategories. I created a custom view called new-arrivals.phtml. I created custom Static Block with the following code in magento

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/new-arrivals.phtml"}}
```

then from Category setting I changed the display setting>CMS Block to the this cms block that I created. And the **display mode** is **static block only**

This view bring all the subcategories of New Arrivals(Bags, Tops, Shoes etc..) with it's products.. [Like on this website](http://www.gojane.com/new-styles.html)   As you can see on this website it is very fast but on my website with my code it is not. [Here it is...](https://www.punkyfish.com/new-arrivals.html)

How can I make this load faster. Cache and everything is enabled. I assume that there is something wrong with my code. thank you for your help.

and this is new-arrivals.phtml content:

Magento CE 1.8.1

```
<?php
            //I load all the subcategories here
            $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
            $categories = $category->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ?>

                <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                    <div class="page-title category-title">
                        <h1>
                            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
                            <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </h1>
                        <?php
                            // here I load all the products for each category      
                            $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');                  
                            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
                            $_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                            ->addAttributeToSort('date_added', 'ASC');

                        ?>
                         <div class="product-count"><?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $this->__('Products'); ?></div>
            <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
            <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="category-products">    


                <?php // Grid Mode ?>
                <?php
                    $_span = 'span3';
                    $_grid_pro = 4;
                ?>

                <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
                <?php $_columnCount = $_grid_pro; //$this->getColumnCount(); ?>
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
<?php // all the others stuff ....... ?>
```

Comment: Hello,

There are two way for doing this work, i will tell you both of you using one i hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load this file using ajax or jquery.
2. Second one you run your code on footer and make one variable then using jquery or java script, you will show your all data in particular div, for example like this

   ```
   if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
       $top_menu .= '<ul>';
       foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
       $prodCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')-      >load($_subcategory->getId())
                   ->getProductCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('no_to_show', array('F' => 78));
                    if($prodCollection->count() !=0){
                   $top_menu .= '<li'; if($current_category == $_subcategory->getId()){$top_menu .= ' id="activesub"';}$top_menu .= '><a href="'.$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory).'">'.$_subcategory->getName().'</a>';
                   $_subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId());
                   $_childsub = $_subcategories->getChildrenCategories(); 
                           $CatTotalCount = count($_childsub); 
                           if($cntr == 0){
                               $firstCount = $CatTotalCount;
                           }
                           if($firstCount >= 7){
                               $loopCount = ($firstCount-1);
                           }else{
                               $loopCount = 6;
                           }
                   if($CatTotalCount >0){
                   $top_menu .= '<ul>';
                   $secCntr = 0;
                       foreach($_childsub as $_child_subcat){
                           $prodCollection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_child_subcat->getId())->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))->addAttributeToFilter('no_to_show', array('F' => 78));

                           if( $secCntr>$loopCount){ 
                               $secCntr = 0;
                                   $top_menu .= '</ul><ul>';
                               }
                               $secCntr++;
                           if($prodCollection2->count() !=0):
                               $top_menu .= '<li'; if($current_category == $_child_subcat->getId()){$top_menu .= ' id="activesub"';}$top_menu .= '><a href="'.$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_child_subcat).'">'.$_child_subcat->getName().'</a></li>';
                               endif;
                          }                            }
                   }
               $top_menu .= '</ul></li>';
           $cntr++;
            }
            $top_menu .= '</ul>';
    }
   ```

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       document.getElementById('top_menus').innerHTML = '';
      jQuery('#mega-menu-8').dcMegaMenu({
      rowItems: '3',
      speed: 'fast',
      effect: 'fade'
      });
      });